# How to display Date and Time in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-mvc, datetime

This is my pojo class method:

```
@Column(name = "TH_EFFECTIVE_TIME")  
    private Date thEffectiveTime;

public Date getThEffectiveTime() {
    return thEffectiveTime;
}

public void setThEffectiveTime(Date thEffectiveTime) {
    this.thEffectiveTime = thEffectiveTime;
}
```

I am getting wrong output like this:

> 1445925903000

Comment: Can you explain little bit more? Where you want to display date and time? Or you want to store current date and time? How you're setting time?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Temporal will convert your timestamp. Remember to persist it as a unix timestamp. Yours is in ms instead of second.

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "TH_EFFECTIVE_TIME")  
private Date thEffectiveTime;

public Date getThEffectiveTime() {
    return thEffectiveTime;
}

public void setThEffectiveTime(Date thEffectiveTime) {
    this.thEffectiveTime = thEffectiveTime;
}
```